# Why is nsurlsessionid connecting to docs.bigassfans.com?

Tags: macos

I saw heavy CPU usage,d then a large upload and checked Little Snitch to see that nsurlsessionid is connecting to 'docs.bigassfans.com'. I know that nsurlsessionid is a system process that syncs to iCloud **but** docs.bigassfans.com and  the relationship with Apple?

docs.bigassfans.com, if typed into Safari's address bar, shows a XML file like:

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<Name>docs.bigassfans.com</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker>
<MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
<IsTruncated>true</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
<Key>Parallax Page/</Key>
<LastModified>2015-10-27T15:30:01.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
<Size>0</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
<Contents>
<Key>Parallax Page/Test/</Key>
<LastModified>2015-11-24T13:04:00.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
<Size>0</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
<Contents>
<Key>Parallax Page/Test/images/BAF_Destrat_LandingPage_Graphics_JG.jpg</Key>
<LastModified>2015-11-24T13:06:58.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"1ba687971f886857466e0dc8c40c040e"</ETag>
<Size>62907</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
</Contents>
...
```

This is an Amazon bucket and Apple seems to be using Amazon along with Azure and others for iCloud but who in Apple would use docs.bigassfans.com? Should i think of that as a red flag?